# Java: Declaring array with do... while

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

My school homework is to declare array with 100 variables.

The actual task is: Declare array with 100 variables. Use do.. while loop to read the data to array. Reading data should be finished when array will be full or when user will enter a negative number.

So far I got:

```
public static void runTask1() {

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] tab = new int [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++);
    System.out.println("Enter number for array ");
    tab [] = read.nextInt();
```

Please help. I'm a total newbie in programming.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? and what do you expect `tab [] = read.nextInt();` to do?

Comment: `for (...) ;` loops over the semicolon (empty statement). Do `for (...) { tab[i] = read.nextInt(); }`

Comment: Have you tried to write some form of the loop yourself? The for loop isn't doing anything as it is at the moment.

Comment: @DavyM There is syntax in php to append to array like that $arrayVariable[]=$nextElement so i think its copy-pasted ;P

Comment: Why are you using a for loop when you need to use a do...while loop?

Comment: I actually don't know. Friend adviced me to use it. I have no idea how to combine array with do... while.

Comment: You also haven't really explained the assignment. "and stop the loop when user will enter <0 value" means: if the user enters a negative number than stop. But what is the purpose of the 100 sized array? As it stands this question is relying too much on assumptions and is contradictory in many ways.

Comment: Is the actual assignment to read a number from input 100 times then stop?

Comment: The actual task is:

Declare array with 100 variables. Use do.. while loop to read the data to array. Reading data should be finished when array will be full or when user will enter a negative number.

Comment: Please update your question to specify that. Like actually read your question and imagine what it reads like to someone other than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do your homework yourself ;)

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] tab = new int [100];
int idx=0;
do{
    System.out.println("Number for array idx "+idx);
    try{
        tab[idx] = read.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }
    if(tab[idx]<0) break;
    idx++;
}while(idx<100)
```

Not compiled, just wrote it here.

Comment: I don't think you would want to put the negative number inside the array since that isn't really part of the data. You should probably check the value before insertion.

Comment: @luckydog32 remove it before break:]

Comment: You can really remove a value from an array, best you can do is overwrite it with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
          int[] tab = new int [100];
          int index = 0;
        while(index < tab.length){
          System.out.println("Enter number for array ");
          tab[index]= read.nextInt();

            if(tab[index]<1) break;
            index++;
          }
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tab)); 
     }
```